# How to randomly hash a 64-bit int

Tags: hash-function

I am trying to write a hash function to map a 64-bit integer to another "random-looking" 64 bit integer.

Here are my requirements:

- I can only use `/`, `*`, `+`, `-`, and `mod`.
- I can choose arbitrary constants, but they are fixed (in order for this to be a true function).

e.g., `h(x) = mod(mod(x, 2^32) * mod(x + 3, 2^32), randPrime(2^15, 2^16)` is a valid expression (`2^32` and `randPrime(2^15, 2^16)` are fixed constants). (I pre-mod by 2^32 to avoid 64-bit overflow.)

However, this particular expression is very bad because very small values of `x` map to deterministic values. What are some ways to mitigate this problem, and create a distribution that looks fairly random?